# Text Content only via button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, keydown

I am trying to get the following: inside my page I have a textbox and button. When the user presses "Enter" on the keyboard it should do the same as clicking the button.

my code looks roughly as follows:

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  .....
  DataContext="{Binding Page1VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding 
        Key="Enter" 
        Command="{Binding Btn_ConfirmCommand}" />
</Page.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid >
     <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedID}" />
     <Button  Command="{Binding Btn_ConfirmCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Inside ViewModel:

```
public Page1VM()
{
   Btn_ConfirmCommand = new RelayCommand(Btn_ConfirmMethod);
}
...
void Btn_ConfirmMethod()
{
  MessageBox.Show(SelectedID);
}
public string SelectedID
{
    get{return selectedID;}
    set
    {
        Set(() => SelectedID, ref selectedID, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedID");
    }
 }
```

> The problem: When I write some content inside the textbox and click the button the messagebox prints the content, but if I press enter key is prints an empty string

Comment: as alternative approach you set the button to be default (`Default="True"` in XAML), so that it will consume the ENTER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `Binding` to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This should cause the source property to get updated on each key stroke. The default value is `LostFocus`.